# Find nondeterminstic finite state automata

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Using the constructions described in the proof of Kleene’s theorem, find nondeterminstic finite state automata of:

- a) `01∗`
- b) `[01]1*`
- c) `00(1*|10)`

Can any body explain please?

Comment: What is your native language?

Comment: i am from india and hindi

Comment: Because the spelling `finita statte automata` seems strange... Where does that spelling come from? The `a` in `finita` suggested perhaps Italian or Spanish or Portuguese to me...

Answer (score 0):

I see each unit as one state.

The third one is a bit tricky:

- After `00`, it could be: `$` (the end), `1*`, or `10`.

Therefore, I could delete the link from B to D, make C the accepted state, and make a link from C to D when the next symbol is 1 (D would still be an accepted state)

[image: NFA]

Comment: The difference between the two approaches I used is this: the first approach corresponds to `/0(0$|0(1*$|10$))/`, while the second approach corresponds to `/00($|11*$|10$)/`, where `$` is the end symbol (accepted state)